# Joomla/Seblod Display Image Thumbnail Only, Link to Lightbox

Tags: image, joomla, gallery, lightbox

I am using Joomla and Seblod.  I would like to create a gallery of thumbnails only, tiled next to one another and when clicked it will open each image into a lightbox (fancybox) and display larger image and description.

Problem I'm having is that when I try to display only the image thumbnails, I get the label "Image" or whatever I enter into Seblod.  I just want plain image thumbnails, no text or any description but when clicked it opens them in the lightbox.  I'm sure this is child's play, but confusing for a a beginning Joomla user like myself.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is built-in Lightbox functionality in Seblod, but it takes a few steps to make it work.  It is even better if you use a custom template, because then you can add regular PHP functions to process your photos.

In any case, to get started, look at the tutorial I wrote on this subject: http://www.seblod.com/support/documentation/seblod-2x/fields/typo/1710-create-a-simple-gallery-with-fieldx-field.html

Comment: can you update your link, as this is exactly what I'm looking for, but the post you're linking to is wrong.
Regards
David

Comment: Hi David.  Sorry, but the Seblod developers altered the material posted on their help boards.  It's out of my hands and I'm not sure what happened to it.

Comment: @David https://www.seblod.com/community/forums/fields-plug-ins/image-gallery-field-x-and-custom-template